# Typhoon errors when collaborating through BitBucket

Tags: swift, typhoon

With my co-worker we run into some strange problems when trying to work on the same swift project through bitbucket.org. Every time after committing and pushing changes on my side and pulling on his side he gets warning that he is unable merge changes and he first need to discard some local changes whereas on my side everything was OK. After he resolves somehow the problem and made new commit-push the same story repeats on my side.

Then we tried to share the project through drop box. But every times he make changes I was unable to run project because of errors like "TyphoonAssembly.h not found", or "TyphoonAssembly.h has duplicate" etc. After that I run 'pod update' and project on my side runs well, but on his side he got new errors.

We both have OSX 10.11 and the same XCode versions. All problems (warnings and errors) are related to [Typhoon framework](https://github.com/appsquickly/typhoon) and they every time different. Any thoughts on what could be the issue?

Comment: When having problems through BitBucket, exactly what files are raising merge conflicts? `.swift` source files that you've edited yourself, or some other files?

Comment: @adpalumbo The odd thing is that XCode unable to merge automatically but "resolve merge conflict dialog" doesn't appear. It seems like something just get broken inside but I can't figure out what exactly.